# Input path does not exist: file:/D:/pigsample_1749383998_1377684507424

Tags: hadoop, cygwin, windows-7-x64, apache-pig

I am facing a wiered issue. 
I am running PIG 0.11 on windows7/64 bit machine with latest version of cygwin.

I am a weblog which I want to order it by userName to have all the user activities for the same user together to feed for next line of processing.

I am starting commandprompt -> cygwin.bat -> on the cygwin console go to D:/ -> pig and typing the following script on grunt shall (local mode).
(Note I've set PIG_HOME, PIG_CLASSPATH correctly).

Script is :

```
USERACTIVITIES = LOAD '/D:/path/of/logs/useractivities' USING org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.CSVExcelStorage(',') AS (datetimeUnProcessed:chararray, username:chararray, request:chararray);
 USERACTIVITIES_ORDERED = ORDER USERACTIVITIES by username;
STORE USERACTIVITIES_ORDERED INTO '/D:/readyfornextinput/useractivities' USING org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.CSVExcelStorage(',');
```

**When I do illustrate USERACTIVITIES_ORDERED I see it going smooth.
But when I do store/dump I face wiered issue.**

It fails by saying : 
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: file:/D:/pigsample_1749383998_1377684507424

When I tried to search this pigsample_number file I could find that in : 
D:/tmp//mapred/local/localRunner

I am not sure how it is happening. 
I am not sure if its windows/cygwin related issue or someone saw this on Linux also.

For reference, you can find the stacktrace attached here:

> 2013-08-28 15:38:28,863 [Thread-46] WARN 
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner - job_local_0004
>   java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.InvalidInputException: Input
>   path does not exist: file:/D:/pigsample_1749383998_1377684507424
>            at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.partitioners.WeightedRangePartitioner.setConf(WeightedRangePartitioner.java:157)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:62)
>            at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:117)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewOutputCollector.(MapTask.java:677)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:756)
>            at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:370)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:214)
>   Caused by:
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.InvalidInputException: Input
>   path does not exist: file:/D:/pigsample_1288777582_1377684802262
>            at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:235)
>           at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigFileInputFormat.listStatus(PigFileInputFormat.java:37)
>            at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:252)
>           at org.apache.pig.impl.io.ReadToEndLoader.init(ReadToEndLoader.java:190)
>           at org.apache.pig.impl.io.ReadToEndLoader.(ReadToEndLoader.java:126)
>            at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.partitioners.WeightedRangePartitioner.setConf(WeightedRangePartitioner.java:131)
>           ... 6 more

Any help on this will be useful.

Comment: Can you try "/D/path/of/logs/useractivities" or "/d/path/of/logs/useractivities"

Comment: Did that too did not help! Infact in cygwin we write /drive:/path....

Comment: Maybe my cygwin version is too low, I try in my cygwin shell. The "D:"  folder is "/cygdrive/d".

Comment: I am using latest cygwin version :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is reproducible only on cygwin environment.
I've documented the root cause and solution [here](http://hadooptips.wordpress.com/2013/09/06/input-path-does-not-exist-file-pigsample_1406502801_1378470046724/)